# PHP - Como preencher um campo usando Curl?

Tags: php, html, libcurl

Qual é o código que uso para preencher campos de uma página da web com `cURL`?
Estes são os campos:

Campo Nome:

```
<li>
    <label for="supporter_full_name">your name*</label>
    <input class="textbox" id="supporter_full_name" name="supporter[full_name]" size="30" type="text" />
</li>
```

Campo Email:

```
<li>
    <label for="supporter_email">email*</label>
    <input class="textbox" id="supporter_email" name="supporter[email]" size="30" type="text" />
</li>
```

Botao:

```
<input class="large blue awesome" id="verificar_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Verificar">
```

Eu tenho uma lista com `nome` e `email` um por baixo do outro, e quero colocá-los numa `textarea` e fazer com que eles sejam testados, e quando o valor for **válido**, ela voltar com o nome e o email escrito na frente - `válido`, e quando o valor for **inválido** ele voltar com o nome e email escrito na frente - `inválido`. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: acho que vc ta confundindo as coisas. cURL não serve pra preencher nada. Ele vai buscar as informações que você precisa, em um arquivo ou em outro servidor. O preenchimento do form pode ser feito somente imprimindo as variáveis junto com o PHP, ou via Javascript. Depende de como vc está montando a página.

Comment: estou montando a pagina em php,como que eu faço ?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "preencher os campos"? Você fala de um [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp), um texto de exemplo que vai ficar no input até que a pessoa digite? O que você quer é validar o formulário? Seja um pouco mais claro e direto.

Comment: O que ele ta tendo fazer, pelo que entendi, é enviar um post usando o curl, porque isso em tese iria "preencher" o campo e "testa-la", como ele se referiu.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é bem simples.

Primeiro a estrutura do arquivo está, segundo voce, ("Eu tenho uma lista com nome e email um por baixo do outro"):

```
nome
email@email.com
```

Então faça um loop carregando o arquivo:

```
// Abre o arquivo
$arquivo = file('arquivo.txt');

$linha = 0; //loop

while ($linha < count($arquivo)) {

    $nome = $arquivo[$linha]; // Primeira linha
    $email = $arquivo[$linha + 1]; // Segunda linha

    // Inicia o CURL
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Valores que deseja enviar.
    $valoresPost = [
        'supporter[full_name]' => $nome,
        'supporter[email]' => $email
    ];

    // Define as configurações do CURL:    
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [

       // Define o URL:
       CURLOPT_URL, 'http://exemplo.com',

       // Indica que é um POST:
       CURLOPT_POST => true,

       // Define a array que irá enviar (neste caso será multipart/form-data):
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $valoresPost,

       // Indica para receber os resultados:
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

    ];

    // Faz a requisição (e obtem resposta):    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Obtem informações do CURL (como código HTTP):
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    // Encerra o CURL:
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($info["http_code"] === 200) {

        // Sucesso

    }else{

        // Falha

    }

    $linha = $linha + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, você primeiro tem que juntar os dois em um array, assim saberá que sempre um número ímpar é um email e um número par é um nome.

Depois disso, você deve fazer a validação dos dados on submit e printar se o dado é válido ou não!

Provavelmente a validação você, ou vai ter que fazer enquanto printa os itens do array ou se criar um item no array para armazenar a validação deles on submit!